# Establish the inequality $\frac{{N - \sqrt{N}} \choose \Omega}{N \choose \Omega} \geq (1-\frac{2\Omega}{N})^{\sqrt{N}}$

Tags: inequality

Establish the inequaity
$$ \frac{{N - \sqrt{N}} \choose \Omega}{N \choose \Omega} \geq (1-\frac{2\Omega}{N})^{\sqrt{N}}$$ where $N > \Omega > \sqrt{N}$ and $N$ is a perfect-square.

**My attempt:**
$$ \frac{{N - \sqrt{N}} \choose \Omega}{N \choose \Omega} = \frac{(N-\sqrt{N})(N-\sqrt{N}-1)\cdots (N-\sqrt{N}-\Omega+1)}{N(N-1)(N-2)\cdots (N-\Omega+1)}$$

Therefore, by manipulating the fraction we obtain:
$$ \frac{{N - \sqrt{N}} \choose \Omega}{N \choose \Omega} = (1-\frac{\sqrt{N}}{N})(1-\frac{\sqrt{N}}{N-1})\cdots (1-\frac{\sqrt{N}}{N-\Omega+1})$$

Since $\Omega > \sqrt{N}$, we will have:
$$(1-\frac{\sqrt{N}}{N})(1-\frac{\sqrt{N}}{N-1})\cdots (1-\frac{\sqrt{N}}{N-\Omega+1}) \geq (1-\frac{\Omega}{N})(1-\frac{\Omega}{N-1})\cdots (1-\frac{\Omega}{N-\Omega+1})$$
Which in turn gives:

$$  \frac{{N - \sqrt{N}} \choose \Omega}{N \choose \Omega} = (1-\frac{\Omega}{N})(1-\frac{\Omega}{N-1})\cdots (1-\frac{\Omega}{N-\Omega+1}) \geq (1-\frac{\Omega}{N-\Omega+1})^{\Omega}$$

If we also assume that $\Omega < \frac{N}{2}$, we get:
$$(1-\frac{\Omega}{N-\Omega+1})^{\Omega}=(\frac{N-2\Omega+1}{N-\Omega+1})^{\Omega}\geq (\frac{N-2\Omega}{N})^{\Omega} \geq (1-\frac{2\Omega}{N})^{\Omega}$$

But since $0<1-\frac{2\Omega}{N}<1$, exponentiation by $\sqrt{N} < \Omega$ will reverse the inequality and it won't finish the proof.

Comment: @mathnoob, in the step " which in turn gives ", you should bound each term with $(1-\frac{\Omega}{N-\Omega+1})$ not $(1-\frac{\Omega}{N})$. Do you agree? Let me know.

Comment: ok. you should find $(\frac{N+1-2Q}{N+1-Q})^{\Omega}$. Now in the numerator $N+1>N$ and in the denominator $N+1-\Omega<N$. Combine the two to arrive at the final result. If I recall, I have done a similar proof while reading the compressive sensing paper

Comment: yes, Q should be omega

Comment: I think it is necessary to assume that $\Omega < \frac{N}{2}$, which is actually assumed later by the authors to use the approximation $\log(1-\frac{2\Omega}{N}) \approx -\frac{2\Omega}{N}$.

Comment: @math.noob looking at the paper, that is exactly the assumption I used too. They seem to not use it for the proof but it is actually needed. I couldn't see how to prove it otherwise.

Comment: @felasfa: Yes. Agreed. But even with that assumption, what we obtain is: $\operatorname{L.H.S.} \geq (1-\frac{2\Omega}{N})^{\Omega}$. The exponent in their inequality is $\sqrt{N}$, but since $0<1-\frac{2\Omega}{N}<1$ exponentiation by $\Omega > \sqrt{N}$ will reverse the inequality and we can not obtain their result simply by exponentiation.

Comment: @felasfa: And actually it is very important to improve the lower bound to $(1-\frac{2\Omega}{N})^{\sqrt{N}}$ because if not, the rest of their reasoning to obtain $\Omega \geq \operatorname{Const} \times M \times \sqrt{N} \times \log(N)$ would become invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments after the question, we assume $\sqrt{N}<Q<\frac{N}{2}$.

As you started,
$$
\dfrac{\binom{N-\sqrt{N}}{\Omega}}{\binom{N}{\Omega}}
= \prod_{k=0}^{\Omega-1} \frac{N-\sqrt{N}-k}{N-k}
= \prod_{k=0}^{\Omega-1} \left(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{N}}{N-k}\right) >
\\
> \left(1-\frac{\sqrt{N}}{N-Q}\right)^{\Omega}
> \left(1-\frac{\sqrt{N}}{N-N/2}\right)^{\Omega}
= \left(1-\frac2{\sqrt{N}}\right)^{\Omega}.
$$

By Bernoulli,
$$
\left(1-\frac2{\sqrt{N}}\right)^{\frac{\Omega}{\sqrt{N}}}
> 1 -\frac2{\sqrt{N}} \cdot \frac{\Omega}{\sqrt{N}} = 1 -\frac{2\Omega}{N},
$$
so
$$
\left(1-\frac2{\sqrt{N}}\right)^{\Omega}
> \left(1 -\frac{2\Omega}{N}\right)^{\sqrt{N}}.
$$

---

$\textbf{Update:}$ I realised that it can be done simpler, without using Bernoulli:
$$
\dfrac{\binom{N-\sqrt{N}}{\Omega}}{\binom{N}{\Omega}} 
= \prod_{k=0}^{\sqrt{N}-1} \frac{N-\Omega-k}{N-k} 
= \prod_{k=0}^{\sqrt{N}-1} \left(1-\dfrac{\Omega}{N-k}\right) >
\left(1-\frac{\Omega}{N-\sqrt{N}}\right)^{\sqrt{N}} >
\left(1-\frac{2\Omega}{N}\right)^{\sqrt{N}}.
$$

Comment: Why $\prod_{k=0}^{\Omega-1} \left(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{N}}{N-k}\right)
> \left(1-\frac{\sqrt{N}}{N-\sqrt{N}}\right)^{\Omega}$? The rest looks clear and fine.

Comment: Opps. You are right./

Comment: Fixed (or at least improved :-) ) the first part.